# Find inverses in a cyclic group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, number-theory, cyclic-groups

I have come up with the following question/problem and want to try to understand and solve it.

Basically, given a cyclic group $G = \mathbb{Z}_{59}^{\times}$; find inverse of $31$ in this group.

Now, I understand that $\mathbb{Z}^{\times}$ in a cyclic group implies that it is multiplicative but then how do I expand the cyclic group? More importantly, how do I find inverses of a number in a group say $31$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have that $\text{gcd}(31,59) = 1$. Now use the extended euclidean algorithm to find the Bezout coefficients to get $1 = 31a + 59b$ for some integers $a$ and $b$. This means that you get $1 = 31 \cdot a$ mod $59$, i.e. $a$ mod $59$ is the inverse of $31$ mod $59$.

As you asked for the computation:

We have

$$59 = 1 \cdot 31 + 28$$

$$31 = 1 \cdot 28 + 3$$

$$28 = 9 \cdot 3 + 1$$

$$3 = 1 \cdot 3 + 0,$$

which once again shows that $\text{gcd}(59,31) = 1$. We now get

$$\small 1 = 28 - 9 \cdot 3 = 28 - 9(31- 28) = -9 \cdot 31 + 10 \cdot 28 = -9 \cdot 31 + 10(59 - 31) = 10 \cdot 59 -19 \cdot 31,$$ i.e. $a = -19$ and $b = 10$. Thus $\overline{-19} = \overline{40}$ is the inverse of $\overline{31}$.

Let me also add a concrete description of the group. Consider $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} = \lbrace \overline{0},\overline{1},\dots,\overline{n-1} \rbrace$. Then we get $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}^{\times} = \lbrace \overline{k} \mid \text{gcd}(k,n) = 1\rbrace$. In the case that $n$ is prime (as in your example) this yields $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}^{\times} = \lbrace \overline{1},\dots,\overline{n-1} \rbrace = (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})\setminus\lbrace \overline{0} \rbrace$.

Comment: Thanks for providing an answer. Just a few questions, why did you jump/do the gcd(31,59)? Also how do you know that the gcd is 1? I assume it is because they are both prime numbers right?

Comment: Also, how do I expand the group? It is all interesting stuff but also complex to understand which is why I was hoping that an example of my own making would help me better understand cyclic groups in general. Would definitely make my day if I understood it!!!

Comment: The extended euclidean algorithm allows you to get such an equation for the gcd. Therefore it was important that the gcd is $1$. Yes. The gcd is $1$ since $31$ (actually also $59$) is a prime number. One of them being prime is enough though as $31 \neq 59$.

Comment: What do you mean by ”expand the group“? Do you want a concrete description of it?

Comment: I see, so what you are saying is that so long as one of the numbers are prime then the gcd is 1? I don't suppose you could kindly help with expanding the cyclic group?

Comment: Usually Z*59 = <1,2,3,....>

Comment: Oops! There was a typo above. I meant to say that $31$ does not divide $59$. A prime number has two divisors: Itself and $1$ And we were able to exclude itself in that case which leads to $1$ being the only common divisor. Let me add that to my answer. I will edit it.

Comment: Thanks for your time Sir, are you able to apply that example to the cyclic group please? I think I'm starting to get this but it would be great to see the theory being applied practically to my own problem

Comment: Well... I just did. You only need to substitute $n$ for $59$ in the latter equation. This means that the group that you are considering consists of $1$ mod $59$, $2$ mod $59$, ..., $58$ mod $59$. I am glad to help more, but you will need to tell me more precisely what you are asking. That is not clear to me.

Comment: No problem Sir, so just a few questions to clarify.

Comment: 1) So Z*59 = ,<1,2,3...,58>?

Comment: 2) I'm stuck and clueless on how to use the extended euclidean algorithm for bezout in my case. i watch a youtube video but im lost because in our case it has to equal 1. Surely a=0 and b=0?

Comment: As in, it would be ever so kind and grateful if you could kindly type out worked example to find the inverse in this case, if it is not too much to ask? If not, no worries

Comment: 1) You are asking whether the group is generated by all its elements, but a group is always generated by all its elements, which is why I believe that you want to say something else. If you want to list its elements you have to use $\lbrace$ and $\rbrace$ and not $\langle$ and $\rangle$.

Comment: No they are not zero. Yes, sure. I can add that as well.

Comment: Thank you so much Sir! You are a legend and now I better understand Cyclic Groups and Bezout Identity. I accepted the answer too

Comment: Glad that I could help.

Comment: Thank you again Sir! By the way Sir, I don't suppose you could help me with one of my other problems? URL: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3322482/working-out-modular-arithmetic-of-a-modulus-that-is-coprime/3322485?noredirect=1#comment6836483_3322485

Comment: There are already lots of answers, so I guess I dont really have to do anything.

Comment: Sir just a quick one, how do I test that this is the correct answer and solution again sorry?

Comment: Inverse elements are unique. Therefore just multiply them and if the result is $1$ it is correct.

Comment: So Sir 40*19? Sorry Sir it would be great if you can kindly show me the correctness with this example

Comment: No, $40 \cdot 31$! We computed the inverse of $31$ and not of $19$. Just calculate: $40 \cdot 31 = 1240 = 1239 + 1 = 21 \cdot 59 + 1$. Thus we have $40 \cdot 31 = 1$ mod $59$.

Comment: Ah Yes Sir Thank YOU!!! You are a LEGEND and I now fully get it. BTW Sir do you know any online Cyclic Group calculators I can use to compute or verify my answers?

Comment: For these types of computations google itself is fine: just type „40 times 31 mod 59“ otherwise you will need to use something like GAP I guess. If you want to compute something then just use some extended euclidean algorithm calculator online etc - just google and you will find what you need.