# Working out modular arithmetic of a modulus that is coprime

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Ever since I started doing work on Bézout Identity and Extended Euclidean Algorithm, I have tried to understand how to do modular arithmetic of big numbers etc. Basically, I have come up with the following problem of my own that I wish to solve:

$t = 24^3 \mod 35$

We know that $35 = 7\cdot 5$ and both $7$ and $5$ are prime numbers. I believe that there is a way of doing modular arithmetic of this nature if the modulus number is coprime like in this case.

I got as far as this:
$$t = 24^3 \mod 7$$
$$t = 24^3 \mod 5$$

What do I do after? It would be great if someone could help me compute this answer as I am very keen to better understand all of this using my own examples.

Please I am new to CRT and any help of steps of calculating this would mean a lot!

Comment: **Hint** $\ t \equiv -1$ mod $5$ & $7$ so also mod $35$ by [CCRT.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/860148/242)

Comment: Look up the Chinese Remainder Theorem to get more details about the technique.

Comment: @MatthewDaly Sorry Sir to be a pain, but I don't suppose you would be ever so kind to apply the Chinese Remainder Theorem for me please? So like a computation breakdown please. I really want to learn new things and believe the only way to best understand it is by using my own example

Comment: One might say that $35$ is *composite* (since it isn't prime) or even *semi-prime* (because it has two prime factors), but it is not "coprime".  That refers to the relation between two numbers with no common factor greater than $1$.

Answer (score 1):

Because $24=21+3\equiv3\pmod7,$

$t\equiv24^3 \pmod 7\implies t\equiv3^3 \pmod 7\implies t\equiv27\equiv\color{purple}{-1}\pmod 7.$

Because $24=25-1\equiv-1\pmod5,$

$ t\equiv24^3 \pmod 5\implies t\equiv(-1)^3 \pmod 7\implies t\equiv\color{purple}{-1}\pmod 5.$

Therefore, since $7$ and $5$ are coprime, by the [constant case of the Chinese remainder theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2005579/does-x-equiv-a-pmod-2-x-equiv-a-pmod-5-rightarrow-x-equiv-a-pmod/2006919#2006919),

$t\equiv\color{purple}-1\equiv34\pmod {7\times5=35}.$

Comment: There is a *huge* gap after "therefore" (esp. at the OP's level).

Comment: Sorry Sir, is this the Chinese Remainder Theorem? I am still confused as to where you got 3^3 (mod 7) from. I don't suppose you can do a more concise breakdown please. It is my fault that I am not good at higher Math

Comment: The long way would be $\color{blue}5\times\color{green}3+\color{blue}7\times\color{green}{-2}=1$ so $t=4\times\color{green}{-2}\times\color{blue}7+6\times\color{green}3\times\color{blue}5$

Comment: @BillDubuque:  I edited, adding a bit more detail

Comment: @user23473433819233d:  $\color{brown}{24}=21+3=7\times3+3\equiv\color{brown}3\pmod7,$ so $\color{brown}{24}^3\equiv\color{brown}3^3\pmod7$

Comment: I dont suppose you could edit the answer to include more detail please Sir. Would be amazing if I could see every step of the calculation

Comment: @user23473433819233d At this point, you might as well learn what CRT is again, and how to use it from an actual book. This ain't it.

Answer (score 0):

I can rewrite tour congruence system as: $$t\equiv 6 \mod 7$$ $$t\equiv 4 \mod 5$$

Because $24^3>7$ then I can calculate the true remainder by (for $7$): $\left (\frac{24^3}{7}-\left \lfloor \frac{24^3}{7} \right \rfloor \right )\cdot 7=6$; and (for $5$): $\left (\frac{24^3}{5}-\left \lfloor \frac{24^3}{5} \right \rfloor \right )\cdot 5=4$.

From the first congruences I obtain: $t\equiv 34 \mod 35$. The solutions are: $t=35k-1$ with $k \in Z$.

Comment: Sorry Sir but where did the 6 and 4 come from? I am now really lost

Comment: $24^3>7$, so the remainder is $\frac{24^3}{7}$ minus its integer part; all times $7$. The same with $5$.

Comment: So sorry Sir I am still lost. I don't suppose you would be kind enough to edit your answer to accomodoate for all of this? I take it this is CRT and if so, it would be great if I could see all the calculation steps